# iPhone Web App charting/graphing libraries

Tags: charts, iphone, javascript

I am chewing through a specification for an **iPhone Web App** (NOT native). The request implies a lot of general charting functionality, mostly **line chart** and **bar charts**. On the implementation side of things, it means a lot of re-formatting of existing web content using an iPhone Web App framework (most likely [JQTouch](http://www.jqtouch.com)).

Given the capabilities of the device browser, is there a specific charting library you'd recommend, which runs acceptably on the mobile Safari with reasonable overhead?

We are interested in the following charting functionality:

- Line and bar series
- Legend display on chart area or outside
- Dynamic series support (e.g. show/hide series)
- Dynamic series creation in JS

I have looked at [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several jQuery based plugins for that (including Flot):

http://www.reynoldsftw.com/2009/02/6-jquery-chart-plugins-reviewed/

And the Filament Group has a nice one as well:

http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_to_jquery_visualize_accessible_charts_with_html5_from_designing_with/

I've used the latter though we eventually scrapped it when we realized we only needed bar graphs and it was easier to just roll-our-own simple implementation using a bit of jQuery animation and some divs.

Answer (score 3):

The free and excellent [Google Chart Tools](http://code.google.com/apis/charttools/index.html) lets you create both static image charts and interactive (javascript) charts.

They look quite nice:

[image]